# Angular Ui Bootstrap modal keyboard = false, not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm been trying to make a modal stay open. but the keyboard option doesn't seems to work. I tried  doing it like I have done a lot of times before.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl:'site.html'
            controller: 'contorller',
            windowClass: 'modal-sm',
            keyboard: false,
            backdrop: 'static',
        });
```

I fell like is a stupid mistake, so can anyone tell what I'm doing worng?

sidenote. the backdrop = static is working fine, so it's only when the user press the esc button that the modal is closing,.